# Versioning using base path mappings in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a pretty straightforward stack: API Gateway sitting in front of a lambda. Currently my paths looks something like:
`/dogs`, `/dogs/{id}`, etc.

All I want to do is add a version to the base path (i.e. `api.dogs.com/v1/dogs`). I tried doing this by creating a custom domain name with a base path mapping of v1 pointing to my stage in API Gateway.

This routes just fine through API Gateway but has issues once it hits the routing logic in my lambda. My lambda is expecting `/dogs` but with the base path mapping the path is actually `v1/dogs`.

What's a good way to approach this? I want to get away from having to deal with versions directly in my code (lambda) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `event` object your lambda function receives you should actually find all the needed information with and without versioning:

```
event = {
  "resource": "/hi",
  "path": "/v1/hi",
  "requestContext": {   
    "resourcePath": "/hi",
    "path": "/v1/hi",
    ....
  },
  ....
}
```

Just adjust the code in your router logic to access the desired attributes should fix your problem and remove the need to care about versioning again in your code.

Comment: Right that makes sense. I guess the challenge for me lies in the framework I'm using (https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) which must be routing based on the path instead of the resource. I'll have to see if there's a way to do that.

Comment: Turns out there is a function in aws-lambda-go-api-proxy for this exact use case (StripBasePath).